# How to create materialized views on an Amazon RDS, coming from a MySQL based Laravel project?

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

So, I guess the title kinda explains my problem here.

I'm working on a project using `Laravel` (most queries using `Eloquent ORM` for getting the data) with `MySQL`, and a specific table is impacting performance so much, that we started looking ways to "materialize it", but as we were using `MySQL` on the project we got some problems. I read about `Flexviews` and some other alternatives, but I'm not sure what can I use here.

For context, the client was having too much users online lately, and the Hostgator server we were using was not being able to keep up with the load, so we did a migration to `Amazon RDS` + `Amazon EC2` VM. The server can now handle the load from active users but the database is struggling due to this specific table that have some joins and also where users can have a lot of filters (`where` clauses) using the search tool on the webapp.

Now, I know `RDS` is not exactly a `MySQL` database so I don't know how compatible it will be with the `MySQL` solutions for materialized views, and we also have the problem that all the dev team machines, and the testing environment are still using `MySQL` for QA and active code development, as the migration to AWS happened as an emergency solution to reduce downtime we were having so we haven't got the time to adapt on this.

So even though I read that `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL` are compatible with `RDS`, I don't know if we should just migrate to PostgreSQL on all "envs", and go to using Materialized Views in `PostgreSQL` hoping that it will translate well on `Amazon RDS`. Does that work well?

Or is it possible to use something like the `Flexviews` project for `MySQL` Materialized Views and it will work on `RDS`? Is there a better alternative here to do a materialized view on `RDS` and that will still work on the other environments?

As I'm a web developer myself (and not much sysadmin/dba experience) and this is my first time actually having to manage an AWS hosted project, I'm not well versed on my possibilities.

Can I have some input from someone more experienced?

*I guess it's important to say that we don't use any fancy features from `MySQL`, so a migration to `PostgreSQL` "logic" and syntax is not gonna be so much of a pain.*

Comment: mysql has no materialized views build in, so you would use standard sql to simulate it, that would work almost everywhere

Comment: RDS can be a lot of different things: sql server, oracle, postgres, mysql, mariadb, aurora (mysql-compatible) or aurora (postgres compatible).  It matters what you are actually using.

Comment: @nbk yeah, I know that MySQL has no MV functionality, so I was studying how to approach something like it on MySQL and read about "flexviews", but I don't know if that translates well with RDS, as I've never used neither before, and know even less about the limitations. I simple view would not solve the issue, as the select with the many "where" clauses is taking almost 1 min to resolve. The best way is really using MV, or at least that what I think based on my previous experience.

Comment: Hey @ysth, so if I just migrate the app to use PostgreSQL the MV features of PostgreSQL will work natively on RDS? I guess that would be the best choice now.

Comment: yes, but moving from one database engine to another is almost never "just migrate", whether in RDS or not.  expect surprises.

Comment: FlexViews is deprecated by the developer. He has moved on to implement similar features in a new MySQL 8 fork he calls LeapDB: https://www.leapdb.com/ You can't add it to an RDS instance, but you can use it as an AMI on the AWS marketplace. I have no affiliation with it (though I worked with the developer years ago at Percona), so check out his website.

Comment: my personal opinion is that views (materialized or not) just make things more difficult and that there's almost always a better way to address a problem.

Comment: i would recommend to have another database (just reader) and use that one for the huge table, so the reader gets slow and not the writer. Another possible solution would be to try to cache stuff using redis, but I have no idea what the code is, what the query is, so it is super hard to help

Comment: A common use case for MVs is a time series and a [_Summary Table_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .  That discusses how to significantly speed up certain common "reports" in a Data Warehouse dataset.